# Регулярное выражение с цифрами, буквами и знаками припенания

Tags: php

Регулярные выражения для меня - что-то далекое и неизведанное. Не могу сейчас сесть изучать, т.к. есть еще множество вещей которые по приоритетности стоят выше. Но в будущем обязательно изучу.

Мне нужно выражение, которое пропустит вот эти строки:
 - Привет, меня зовут Марк! :)
 - I'm not a robot. I was burn in 1822.
Т.е. нужно пропускать только русские и английские буквы, цифры и знаки препинания, но не нужно - никаких китайских, греческих и прочих символов (их используют для обхода спам-чекера). Я бы мог, конечно, заменять их str_replace'ом. Но как бы много исключений и замен я не сувал, их обходят, используя какие-нить еще символы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9\s?!,.'Ёё]+$`

`^` - начало строки

`$` - конец строки

`[]` - начало перечисления допустимых символов

`\s` - пробелы

[Ссылка для тестов](https://regex101.com/r/h8357R/1)

Comment: в метку `\s` входят не только пробелы `[ \f\n\r\t\v]`, а конкретно пробел обозначается через просто пробел.

Comment: Да и еще введя в ваш текст букву `Ё` регулярка перестанет работать.

Comment: Предложу аналог `^[\p{L}\d ?!,.']+$`

Answer (score 0):

Вот это должно подойти:

```
^[?!,.а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9\s]+$
```

Comment: Это только для русских букв. Нужны еще английские и '. 
^[?!,'.а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9\s]+$ Сработает так?