# Символы в регулярных выражениях

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Два вопроса за день это конечно ммммм, но не могу не спросить:

Есть форма данные из которой передаются на следующую страницу.
Конкретно сейчас данная форма прогоняется через:

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9]/', $something)
```

что позволяет отфильтровать на предмет чего угодно кроме английских больших и маленьких букв и цифр от 0 до 9. Однако если мы хотим принимать нормальный текст нужны ещё пробелы, точки, запятые, восклицательные и вопросительные знаки.

Как настроить фильтр так, чтобы он пропускал всё это, но не пропускал любые другие символы?
Также прошу не закидывать кампнями и про гугл пожалуйста не говорить, там выкидывает либо на конструкторы, которые только проверяют на валидность написанное руками, либо на статьи в которых рассказано только про a-zA-Z0-9.

Comment: Ну так добавьте в набор то что вам нужно.

Comment: @u_mulder так в том и вопрос: КАК добавить? В гугле про это ничего не сказано. При смене на [a-zA-Z0-9.,!?] всё перестаёт работать полностью, при смене на [a-zA-Z0-9][.][,][!][?] тоже.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1009346/178087

Comment: `/[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,!?]/` у вас должно работать. Если не работает, покажите свой код.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew короче оказалось, что чтобы работал этот вариант обязательно дописать в начале ^ и в конце +$, иначе при вписании любых других символов всё равно проходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
preg_match('/^[\wА-Яа-я\s?!,\.\\\/&()"\']+$/m']+$/', $something)
```